# Notification in another page while submitting a form in one page in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a notification in main page while submitting a form in another page.When I submit a form in another page then it navigates to the main page and shows the notification how can these be done in react js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux and set the notifications objects with the message you want from the secondary page.

Now , whenever you are on your main page read that notifications object to check if their are any notifications and show them.

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand, You need to some socket based server that in one page push data and in another pull data and alert....

Or in js open window or tab like a popup! and control  it in first page, something like this: `var myw = window.open("", "SecPage", "width=1600, height=1000");` and wait for some event from `myw` in first page